# How to create paypal buttons from an html form?

Tags: javascript, paypal, forms

I am creating an eshop in pure html and want to create a html form where a user adds product information and pictures. I am planning to use paypal for payment processing and I wonder if it's possible to create the paypal buttons for each product without having to go to the paypal website.
Does the paypal allow button creation through a javascript api or even with the use of an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

The Buy Now button can be generated via javascript, here is [the documentation](https://github.com/paypal/JavaScriptButtons#javascript-api)

> **PAYPAL.apps.ButtonFactory.create(business, data, type, parentNode)**
>
> Creates and returns an HTML element that contains the button code.
>
> ```
> business - A string containing either the business ID or the business email
> data - A JavaScript object containing the button variables
> type - The button type, e.g. "buynow", "cart", "qr"
> parentNode - An HTML element to add the newly created button to (Optional)
> ```

Comment: I don't get it.There is no authentication with paypal when creating buttons.You only need to know the merchant's email and you are able to create product buttons. Did I misunderstood something?Is there any tutorials explaining the whole procedure of creating buttons with this library?Thank you